# Need assistance with onclick

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am building an Android app and basically I want it to count tapping on the screen(anywhere). Now I tried to put the `RelativeLayout` to have `android:clickable="true"` and my 1 `TextView` the same, but when I try to start the `Activity` the app crashes. I would like it to show time, lets say 30 seconds, and then to count taps for these 30 seconds.

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.orion.peky.thetapgame.Game">       

         <TextView
             android:text="Tap to start"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:textSize="50dp"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
             android:id="@+id/tekst" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
 MAIN package com.orion.peky.thetapgame;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.view.Menu; 
 import android.view.MenuItem; 
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;



 public class Game extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
     }
     TextView tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
     int brojac=0;

     public void broji(View view){
         brojac=brojac+1;
         tekst.setText("Tapped "+brojac+" times");
     } }
```

Comment: i cant get to it, my laptop can not run the emulatio and i cant run it live on the phone while conected to the laptop...BTW i removed android:clickable="true" and android:onclick="broji" to run it without it...

Comment: move `tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);` inside onCreate of Activity after `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with this lines outside the `onCreate()` method:

```
 TextView tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
 int brojac=0;
```

put inside the `onCreate()` method, declare the `TextView` tekst as a Class variable and then you can use it inside your `broji()` method too:

```
public class Game extends Activity {

private TextView tekst;
private int brojac=0;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
      tekst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
     }

     public void broji(View view){
         brojac=brojac+1;
         tekst.setText("Tapped "+brojac+" times");
     } 
}
```

Comment: and in this world, nobody can explain anything. Indeed, you deserve +1 for not showing any explanation :)

Comment: Working now i knew i had a mistake but didnt notice it was a global variable xd thanks